# Question about computing denominator in Bayes' theorem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I have a question which I found on the web:

> Two boxes are placed in a cupboard out of which the first box contains 1 black and 3 red balls and the second box contains 4 black and 2 red balls. A ball picked at random from one of the boxes is found to be black. What is the probability that the ball is drawn from the first box?

I understand I have to use Bayes theorem for it, so something like $$Pr (First | Black) = \frac{Pr(Black|First) Pr(First)}{Pr(Black)}$$

Now my confusion is in how to compute $Pr(Black)$, the website calculates it using the sum of each individual marginals: $Pr(Black, First) + Pr(Black, Second)$. My question is why can't I just combine the two and say it is half?  Since if we are going to be picking the box randomly as well as pick the ball randomly, so $Pr(Black) = \frac{1 + 4}{10}$, but that isn't right apparently?

Comment: Why should it be $\frac 12$?  It's $\frac 14$ if you pick from the first box, and $\frac 46=\frac 23$ if you pick from the second.  Those do not average to $\frac 12$.

Comment: @lulu since we are picking randomly, can't you imagine those two boxes are one? So if you pick either red or black, probability of that is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The mechanism for selection is specified. You are not choosing a ball at random, you first choose a box at random, and then you choose a ball.  Very different.  Suppose one box had only a single black ball, and the other had $4$ black and $5$ red.  Then the probability of choosing black would be $\frac 12\times \left(1+\frac 45\right)$ which is *much* greater than $\frac 12$.

Comment: Typo:  meant to write $\frac 12\times \left( 1+\frac 49\right)$.

Comment: "A ball picked a random from one of the boxes" doesn't clearly imply lulu's interpretation, but that is probably the intended one.